# Paramiko does not give correct return code using grep

Tags: python-3.x

The code does not give me the correct return code when using the grep in the command output looping over by selecting each python list and checking if it exists or not.

Python list:

```
 for i in range(len(sharenames)):
       path = sharenames[i]
       cmd="isi quota quotas list -az \| grep \"path\""
       stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
       if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() == 0:
               print(f'Return code: {stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()}')
               print("Command executed Succesfully")
       else:
               print(sharenames[i])
               print("Command executed Un-Successful")
       
  client.close()
  del client, stdin, stdout, stderr`enter code here`
```

Comment: `cmd="isi quota quotas list -az \| grep \"path\""` is `path` in this statement not supposed to be replaced by the actual path? What return code do you get and and what were you expecting?

Comment: What is `client`?